# SQL Server many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many relationship problem:

The facts:

- A Prefecture has many Municipalities.
  A Municipality belongs to a single Prefecture.
  (one-to-may relationship)
- A Prefecture has many Cities.
  A City belongs to a single Municipality.
  (one-to-may relationship)
  Now
- A Municipality can have one or more Cities.
- A City can have one or more Municipalities.
  That is, Municipalities and Cities have a many-to-many relation.

I think of creating a tblMunicipalityCity join table to serve the many-to-many relationship:

```
                                      [tblMunicipalityCity]    
[tblPrefecture] PrefectureID       ->  PrefectureID      
[tblMunicipality] MunicipalityID  ->  MunicipalityID  
[tblCity] CityID                  ->  CityID
```

Would you think this is a good solution?

Thanks in advance for your help.
Corbex

Comment: The main problem is in conflicting statements: `City belongs to a single Municipality` and  `Municipalities and Cities have a many-to-many relation`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need a fourth table that represents the many-to-many relationship between the Cities and the Municipalities.
That table is always made of the PK of both tables you want to join, plus eventually some extra properties, specific to that relationship.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model

Comment: Thank everybody for your answers!  
Yes that's what I think too. The problem is the tblPrefecture table as it relates with a one-to-many relationship to both the tblMunicipality and tblCity tables.  
  
I think I shouldn't include the PrefectureID field as a FK in tblMunicipality and tblCity tables but instead include it in tblMunicipalityCity junction table.  
  
What do you think?  
  
Thanks again, Corbex

Comment: Both child tables (Cities and Municipalities) may have a link to the Prefectures. That is not a problem at all...

Comment: So you think it's better to include PrefectureID as FK to both tblCity and tblMunicipality tables than include it in tblMunicipalityCity junction table?

Comment: I did not think about that option...but no, I wouldn't. It's the City and/or the Municipality which belong to a Prefecture, not the relationship. Plus, adding the FK to the relationship table would create unwanted duplicates in many situations.

Comment: I think so too as both Municipalities and Cities are related to Prefectures in a one-to-many relationship. So when Municipalities and Cities are related to one-another through the tblMunicipalityCity junction table there shouldn't be allowed to differ in terms of the Prefecture relationship - that is, both Municipalities and Cities should be related to the SAME Prefecture.

Answer (score 0):

Juste create a join table with municipality_id and city_id, both composing the primary key, that's it.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your answers! Yes that's what I think too. The problem is the tblPrefecture table as it relates with a one-to-many relationship to both the tblMunicipality and tblCity tables. I think I shouldn't include the PrefectureID field as a FK in tblMunicipality and tblCity tables but instead include it in tblMunicipalityCity junction table. What do you think? Thanks again, Corbex

Answer (score 0):

extract the two ids that make the many to many relationship between Cities and Municipalities into a separate composite table, where both foreign keys become the primary key

Comment: Thanks everybody for your answers! Yes that's what I think too. The problem is the tblPrefecture table as it relates with a one-to-many relationship to both the tblMunicipality and tblCity tables. I think I shouldn't include the PrefectureID field as a FK in tblMunicipality and tblCity tables but instead include it in tblMunicipalityCity junction table. What do you think? Thanks again, Corbex